# Xamarin Forms - use iOS native library

Tags: xamarin

I have mobile applicaction using Xamarin Forms. I have also library `something.framework` written in **Objective-C** and sample project in XCode.

I need to use this library in cross-platform application. I have added native reference to this library at `Xamarin.iOS` project. I use dependency interface to manage button's action from Xamarin Forms into Xamarin-iOS. The thing is that Visual Studio is not connecting native reference to library with my code in class. Using directive is not accessing native library so I have many errors when I try to use methods form library. I have already read Microsoft's instructions about binding native libraries but not answers came.

How to solve this?

Here are logs from terminal when I have used Objective Sharpie:

```
Johns-Mac-mini:~ johnmiller$ sharpie bind
-output=InfColorPickerCustom -namespace=InfColorPickerCustom ~/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/*.h -sdk=iphoneos12.1 Parsing 8 header files... In file included from /var/folders/_g/mb3qv73j16d_mdwzb8bf5hww0000gn/T/tmp765fc04f.h:2: /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorIndicatorView.h:19:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute] @property (nonatomic) UIColor* color; ^ /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorIndicatorView.h:19:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute] In file included from /var/folders/_g/mb3qv73j16d_mdwzb8bf5hww0000gn/T/tmp765fc04f.h:3: In file included from /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker.h:60: /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorPickerController.h:28:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute] @property (nonatomic) UIColor* sourceColor; ^ /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorPickerController.h:28:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute] /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorPickerController.h:29:1: warning: no 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is assumed [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute] @property (nonatomic) UIColor* resultColor; ^ /Users/johnmiller/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/InfColorPickerController.h:29:1: warning: default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-GC object [-Wobjc-property-no-attribute]

Binding...   [write] ApiDefinitions.cs   [write] StructsAndEnums.cs

Binding Analysis:   Automated binding is complete, but there are a few APIs which have been flagged with [Verify] attributes. While the entire binding should be audited for best API design practices, look more closely at APIs with the following Verify attribute hints:

  ConstantsInterfaceAssociation (200 instances):
    There's no foolproof way to determine with which Objective-C interface an extern variable declaration may be associated. Instances of these are bound as [Field] properties in a partial interface into a nearby concrete interface to produce a more intuitive API,
    possibly eliminating the 'Constants' interface altogether.

  MethodToProperty (193 instances):
    An Objective-C method was bound as a C# property due to convention such as taking no parameters and returning a value (non-void return). Often methods like these should be bound as properties to surface a nicer API, but sometimes false-positives can occur and
    the binding should actually be a method.

  StronglyTypedNSArray (42 instances):
    A native NSArray* was bound as NSObject[]. It might be possible to more strongly type the array in the binding based on expectations set through API documentation (e.g. comments in the header file) or by examining the array contents through testing. For example,
     an NSArray* containing only NSNumber* instances can be bound as NSNumber[] instead of NSObject[].

  PlatformInvoke (3256 instances):
    In general P/Invoke bindings are not as correct or complete as Objective-C bindings (at least currently). You may need to fix up the library name (it defaults to '__Internal') and return/parameter types manually to conform to C calling conventionsfor the target
    platform. You may find you don't even want to expose the C API in your binding, but if you do, you'll probably also want to relocate the definition to a more appropriate class and expose a stronger type-safe wrapper. For P/Invoke guidance, see http://www.mono-
    project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/.

  InferredFromMemberPrefix (29 instances):
    The name of this originally anonymous declaration was taken from a common prefix of its members.

  Once you have verified a Verify attribute, you should remove it from the binding source code. The presence of Verify attributes intentionally cause build failures.
     For more information about the Verify attribute hints above, consult the Objective Sharpie documentation by running 'sharpie docs' or visiting the following URL:

    http://xmn.io/sharpie-docs 6 warnings generated.

Done. Johns-Mac-mini:~ johnmiller$
```

Comment: Have you created the C# bindings for the ObjC framework? Just adding a native reference to the framework does create the bindings, you either have to manually create them or use Sharpie to bootstrap those bindings.

Comment: Just in case if you have that framework available in Cocoapod then its even easier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod

Comment: Have you referred to this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries?tabs=windows).And show some log info or image will be helpful.

Comment: I have generated ApiDefinition.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs from terminal using Sharpie but they have more than 60 000 lines and 11 000+ errors. How to avoid those conlicts?

Comment: @YoungEddie Okey , first need to analyze the error log that appears , then will find the reason .

Comment: I have done 4 different library bindings and in all cases there are generated 2 files: 60.000+ lines code ApiDefenitions.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs with 25.000+ lines. I added report to main question. The last one was sample from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. There was a need to use scope when using Objective Sharpie. Simple add "-scope ~/Desktop/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker". Then Sharpie is generating small files.